# How to fetch only the first record in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am using Core Data and I only want to fetch the first record in my dataset, is it possible?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use the `setFetchLimit:` method on NSFetchRequest to limit the number of records fetched. So if you only want the first record:

```
// Given some existing NSFetchRequest *request and NSManagedObjectContext *context:
[request setFetchLimit:1];
NSError *error;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Note that the call to `executeFetchRequest:error:` will still return an NSArray; you still need to pull the first object off the array before you can work with it, even though it's an array of size 1.

**Another, less efficient method:** Depending on your store type, limiting the fetch may produce dramatic performance speedups. If it doesn't, however, or you're not that worried about performance, and you might use more data later, you can just pull the first object off the array ahead of time:

```
// Given some existing result NSArray *results:
NSManagedObject *firstManagedObject = [results firstObject];
```

If you're sure that the array has an object in it, you can even get it into another array (for use in a UITableViewController, for example) by doing this:

```
// Again, with some NSArray *results:
NSArray *singleObjectResult = [results subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
```

Comment: This code could crash if there is no record matching the request predicate.
Prefer my answer for safer code

Comment: Edited to use `-firstObject` and warn about the `-subarrayWithRange:` call.

Answer (score 16):

Of course it partially depends on what you mean by the "first record". You may not only need to set the fetch limit to 1, but also to sort the results in the fetch.

For example, I have a bunch of `User` objects in my database, and I want to find the first one who created an account. (Assuming I already have the model for `User`, including one attribute named `accountCreatedDate`.)

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"accountCreatedDate" ascending:YES]; // ascending YES = start with earliest date

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = entity;
request.sortDescriptors = @[ sortDescriptor ];
request.fetchLimit = 1;

NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

User *result = fetchResults.firstObject; // nil on failure; check value of 'error'
```

If you don't sort the results before limiting the fetch, there's no telling what results will be returned "first".

Answer (score 2):

I used Objective-C categories to add an `NSManagedObject` class method called `firstInManagedObjectContext:`.

#### Source Code

```
// NSManagedObject+Additions.h

@interface NSManagedObject (Acani)

+ (NSString *)entityName;
+ (NSEntityDescription *)entityInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
+ (NSManagedObject *)firstInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;

@end


// NSManagedObject+Additions.m

#import "NSManagedObject+Additions.h"

@implementation NSManagedObject (Acani)

+ (NSString *)entityName {
    return NSStringFromClass([self class]);
}

+ (NSEntityDescription *)entityInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    return [NSEntityDescription entityForName:self.entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
}

+ (NSManagedObject *)firstInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[self entityInManagedObjectContext:context]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    [fetchRequest release];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Fetch sender error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        return nil;
    } else if ([fetchedObjects count] > 0) {
        return [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

#### Usage

Add these files to your project and be sure to link them to your target. Then, `#import "NSManagedObject+Additions.h"` in the `.m` files where you use the `firstInManagedObjectContext:` class method.

Call it from any concrete (not abstract) subclass of `NSManagedObjectContext`. Just pass it the `NSManagedObjectContext *context` from which to fetch the managed object. The method detects the `(NSString *)entityName` from the name of the class on which it's called. Just remember to cast the result for a clean build (without warnings).

I'm using this for a managed object class of which I know I only have one saved instance. If you have more than one saved instance, you may want to add an `NSSortDescriptor` as @Craig McMahon suggests. You could also try to sort by `objectID` instead of `accountCreatedDate` if all objects are created on the same device. I'm not sure, however, if the object IDs are ordered.

#### Example

Imagine you have an `Event` object that descends from `NSManagedObjectContext`. You could do:

```
Event *event = (Event *)[Event firstInManagedObjectContext:context];
```

#### Blocks

After reading the [Pragmatic Studio's iOS 4 Blocks Tutorial](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/15/ios4-blocks-2), I realized that this code could be improved and made even more modular by adding another function, call it `+ fetch` and adding a `NSFetchRequestBlock` (which would take the `fetchRequest` as its argument) & `NSFetchRequestFailureBlock` as arguments to customize the fetch request and the handling of the fetch request error, respectively. I challenge you to tackle that! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just set the `fetchLimit` property of your `NSFetchRequest` to 1, then pick up the first element from the results `NSArray` using the `firstObject` method to avoid any `index out of bound for empty array` error.

Here is the code example :

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ENTITY_NAME" inManagedObjectContext:yourMoc];
NSPedicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"PREDICATE FORMAT"];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
[request setFetchLimit:1];

NSError *error;
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSManagedObject *object = [results firstObject];
if (object) {
    // there is at least one object matching you predicate
} else {
    // there is no object matching your predicate in the moc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt.
N.B. the Book Entity inherits from NSManagedObject.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"isbn ==9780786660506"];

Book *book = (Book*) [CoreDataHelper getEntityFromFetchedResultsController:@"Book" :predicate :nil :YES :application.managedObjectContext];


if (book !=nil)    NSLog(@"book entity %@",book.title);
```

Bang this in a static helper class called CoreDataHelper

```
+ (NSManagedObject*)getEntityFromFetchedResultsController: (NSString*) entityName : (NSPredicate *) predicate : (NSString*) sortKey : (BOOL) sortAscending : (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext
{

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity]; 
[request setFetchLimit:1];

// If a predicate was passed, pass it to the query
if(predicate != nil)
{
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
}

// If a sort key was passed, use it for sorting.
if(sortKey != nil)
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortKey ascending:sortAscending];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptors release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
}

NSError *error;

NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy] autorelease];


    if (error !=nil){
NSLog(@"error %@", error);
}
   if ([mutableFetchResults count] >0)
    {
   NSManagedObject *firstObject = [mutableFetchResults objectAtIndex:0];
   return firstObject;
    }else
    {
      return nil;
    }

}
```